# echo into a .sh file

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a script with the goal of generating a large number of other scripts. I am using a for loop that echo's the text of the code I want for each script and then > it into a .sh file. Here is how I wrote it:

```
#!/bin/bash


for i in {1..30} ; do

echo

"#!/bin/bash
#$ -N DT_STAR_$i
#$ -l mem_free=200G
#$ -pe openmp 4
#$ -q bio,abio,pub8i

module load STAR/2.5.2a


STAR  --genomeDir /dfs1/bio/dtatarak/indexes/STAR_Index --readFilesIn 
DT_$i.read1.fastq DT_$i.read2.fastq --runThreadN 4 --outFileNamePrefix 
/David_data1/DT_$i"  > DT_STAR_map_$i.sh


done
```

Basically what I want it to do is take all the lines of code inside the ' ' and put them into a new .sh file each time changing DT_i to DT_1, DT_2, DT_3, etc. when I run this script in the terminal, it does make all of the .sh files, but doesn't put anything in them. and it prints the contents of the quotes to my screen with the message "No such file or directory". I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't start the string to echo on a different line from the `echo` command itself. The newline at the end of the `echo` line ends that command, and then the string is treated as a command of its own to execute. But there's no command with that name, so you get an error.

Also, you can't split the `STAR` command across multiple lines as you have.

```
for i in {1..30} ; do

echo "#!/bin/bash
#$ -N DT_STAR_$i
#$ -l mem_free=200G
#$ -pe openmp 4
#$ -q bio,abio,pub8i

module load STAR/2.5.2a

STAR  --genomeDir /dfs1/bio/dtatarak/indexes/STAR_Index --readFilesIn DT_$i.read1.fastq DT_$i.read2.fastq --runThreadN 4 --outFileNamePrefix  /David_data1/DT_$i"  > DT_STAR_map_$i.sh

done
```

A more common way to write multiple lines is with a here-doc.

```
for i in {1..30} ; do

cat <<EOF > DT_STAR_map_$i.sh
#!/bin/bash
#$ -N DT_STAR_$i
#$ -l mem_free=200G
#$ -pe openmp 4
#$ -q bio,abio,pub8i

module load STAR/2.5.2a

STAR  --genomeDir /dfs1/bio/dtatarak/indexes/STAR_Index --readFilesIn DT_$i.read1.fastq DT_$i.read2.fastq --runThreadN 4 --outFileNamePrefix /David_data1/DT_$i
EOF

done
```

Comment: The STAR command itself is written as one line in my code. I'm not familiar with the formatting on this website, and that's why it ended up that way in my post. I didn't know that about the echo command being interrupted by the new line. Thanks I'll give that a try!

Comment: That worked great! Thanks I wasn't aware of that aspect of echo syntax.